# How can I update a 2 variables from two inputs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I can't get them to output both the selections at the same time. Is this possible? One side is always undefined. I have tried so many things, but when I console.log I just cannot get them to log at the same time. I would like the default values to be "all", and then either side would update depending on what is clicked.

```js
function combo(a, b) {
  a = a.value
  b = b.value
  console.log(a, b)
}
```

```html
<label for="food">Please select a food: </label>
<select id="food" onchange="combo(this,'all')">
  <option value="100">Select</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="cheese">cheese</option>
  <option value="pickle" pickle</option>
</select>

<label for="sort">Please sort: </label>
<select id="sort" onchange="combo('all',this)">
  <option value="100">Select</option>
  <option value="smell">smell</option>
  <option value="texture">texture</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. So you want the `sort` to change when `food` is selected and vice-versa?

Comment: I just want the variables to update whenever a change occurs. So I can eventually use them both in an if/else statement to sort my values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider getting the values explicitly instead of trying to go through a `onchange` attribute handler.

```js
const foodSelect = document.getElementById("food");
const sortSelect = document.getElementById("sort");

function selectHandler() {
  const food = foodSelect.value;
  const sort = sortSelect.value;
  console.log(`Food: ${food} | Sort: ${sort}`);
}

foodSelect.addEventListener("change", selectHandler);
sortSelect.addEventListener("change", selectHandler);
```

```html
<label for="food">Please select a food: </label>
<select id="food">
  <option value="100">Select</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="cheese">cheese</option>
  <option value="pickle" pickle</option>
</select>

<label for="sort">Please sort: </label>
<select id="sort">
  <option value="100">Select</option>
  <option value="smell">smell</option>
  <option value="texture">texture</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This excellent and is exactly what I was after. I am extremely thankfull. Please could you explain what the '$' section is for in the console.log? Is this Jquery?

Comment: @simonpeters2332 Oh, no that's just [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which let you do variable substitution in Strings.  It would be the same as writing `console.log("food: " + food + " " + "sort: " + sort);`  That's just really hard to read/write so you can use templates to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, less lines.

```js
function combo() {  
  let food = document.getElementById("food");
  let sort = document.getElementById("sort");
  console.log(food.options[food.selectedIndex].text + ', ' + sort.options[sort.selectedIndex].text);  
}
```

```html
<label for="food">Please select a food: </label>
<select id="food" onchange="combo()">
  <option value="100">Select</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="cheese">cheese</option>
  <option value="pickle"> pickle</option>
</select>

<label for="sort">Please sort: </label>
<select id="sort" onchange="combo()">
  <option value="100">Select</option>
  <option value="smell">smell</option>
  <option value="texture">texture</option>
</select>
```